# "from module import class" importing other classes from same module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Given the following files:

```
a.py
-----
class CommonClass(object):
    def do_thing(self):
        pass

b.py
-----
from a import CommonClass

class SubClassA(CommonClass):
    def do_thing(self):
        print("I am A")

class SubClassB(CommonClass):
    def do_thing(self):
        print("I am B")

c.py
-----
from a import CommonClass
from b import SubClassA

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for member in CommonClass.__subclasses__():
        member().do_thing()
```

I would expect only `SubClassA` is imported, and visible when looping through subclasses of `CommonClass`, but it seems `SubClassB` is imported as well.

I am running Python 3.8.5 and this is the output of `python3 c.py`:

```
$ python3 c.py      
I am A
I am B
```

How can I only import the classes I want?

Comment: `__subclasses__()`  return all classes which are inherited from a base class that is why you're getting both outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **did** import only `SubClassA` to `c.py`. This can be tested by doing

```
x = SubClassB()
```

or

```
x = b.SubClassB()
```

Both will result in a `NameError`.

The thing is, that  when you `import` a file, it is actually being ran, **even when using `from x import y`**!

This can be easily seen by adding a `print("I'm from b.py")` at the end of `b.py` and then running `c.py`.

This makes both `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` be subclasses of `CommonClass`, which you imported. So, while you don't have access to the `SubClassB` **name**, it is still a subclass of `CommonClass` and you can access it from there.

---

In general you don't have to import a module to be able to use its objects. Importing expands your namespace to include that module so you can create an object directly. You can still use this module's objects even without importing it if you acquired them in some other way (like importing a third module which returns objects from the second one).

---

Anyway right now, you are not really using even the imported `SubClassA`. If you want to "allow" certain classes to be considered only from an external source, you can create an *allowed* set of classes:

```py
from a import CommonClass
from b import SubClassA

allowed_classes = {SubClassA}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for member in CommonClass.__subclasses__():
        if member in allowed_classes:
            member().do_thing()
```

Which only prints `I am A`

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to avoid this behaviour? For my specific purpose iterating through subclasses is easy enough, but I would like to explicitly specify which subclasses I want to import.

Comment: That should work! I was hoping to avoid typing the allowed classes multiple times, but I think this is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

```
from a import CommonClass
from b import SubClassA

if __name__ == "__main__":

    h = CommonClass.__subclasses__()[0]()
    h.do_thing()
```

You can do this.